# PHPUnit with SQlite database throws 'too many connections' error.

Tags: sqlite, laravel, phpunit

I am using SQlite database for testing my backend with my Laravel APP. 
The problem I get is that when I am running a test (I have approximately 800 tests), they just hang at test around 120-130 with an error:

```
'Too many connections'
```

Whats odd is that they run without any problem on the server. Also I have another machine which has Linux as well as server - and tests also stop there. And my colleague also has troubles when running tests, though he gets an error earlier in another file.

If I run all tests manually one by one - they pass without any problem.

Comment: Hard to tell without some code.

Comment: I would suggest changing the sqlite database config type to memory for testing though, `$this->app['config']->set('database.connections.sqlite.database', ':memory:');`. This may fix it. You would do this in tests/TestCase::setUp()

Answer (score -2):

Go with MYSQL. SQlite database is very small. MySQL comes with most of the features. I think it will solve your problem. http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Comment: If it was my project and I started from scratch I would do that, but right now that is not an option.

Comment: Although this is a good recommendation, it does address the error that the OP mentioned. It is also confusing to just say "SQlite database is very small"